# My jquery this correct?

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, blink

I am wondering if my jquery function is correct

```
<script>
window.blinker = setInterval(function(){
  if(window.alerta){
    $('a.cadastrotopo').css('color','#346698');
    $('a.cadastrotopo').css('text-decoration','underline');
      window.alerta=false;
    }
    else{
      $('a.cadastrotopo').css('color','#000');
      $('a.cadastrotopo').css('text-decoration','none');
      window.alerta = true;
    }
},500);
</script>
```

is working ok, but I wonder if I'm doing the right way.

I thank you.

Comment: If you're writing a blink, you're definitely doing it wrong :)

Comment: No. You're making some text flash. That's *never* going to be correct ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally I would use CSS more, particularly classes:

```
a.cadostropo {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.alert { 
  color: #346698;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

and then the solution becomes trivial:

```
setInterval(toggleAlert, 500);

function toggleAlert() {
  $("a.cadostropo").toggleClass("alert");
}
```

One side note: instead of multiple `css()` calls you can use anonymous objects to specify multiple properties.

```
$("a.cadostropo").css({color: "#346698", textDecoration: "underline"});
```

That being said, I prefer not to use hardcoded CSS manipulation like this. Favour classes. They're far more flexible and you don't have to worry about destructive changes and rolling them back.

Comment: Perfect. Fwiw, if 'window.alerta' is somehow important beyond the scope of the immediate function then 'window.alerta = !window.alerta;' would be preferable to the if/else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are, although you could combine the css declarations to look like this.

```
.css({'color' : "#346698", 'text-decoration' : "underline"});
```

Comment: cletus's version would be more efficient, as it would remove the if statement. Mine would just be better if you needed to do something other than a simple toggle (i.e. somewhere else in your code)